# ActionScript 3 | [Error 1120] Access of undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3

i try to set value for my two variables in my Class. But flash throw me exception - `'Access of undefined property myFirstText'` and `'Access of undefined property mySecondText'`. Where is my STUPID mistake?

My class:

```
package eu.gabrielatanasov.myclasses {

    public class myClass {

        private var myFirstText: String;
        private var mySecondText: String;

        public function myClass() {
            trace('Class loaded!');
        }

        public static function getMyText($myFirstText: String, $mySecondText: String): void {
            myFirstText = $myFirstText;
            mySecondText = $mySecondText;
        }

        private static function justTrace(): void {
            trace('My first text: ' + myFirstText + '\n' + 'My second text: ' + mySecondText);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance variables cannot be set from a class (static) function. That's why you are getting the error.

If you want to set your variables with a static function, those variables have to be static as well. Remember the static functions do not have access to 'this' inside of the function and you are setting:

```
this.myFirstText = $myFirstText; //this: because they are instance variables; there is no this in a static function, error
```

Comment: How do you mean 'function constructor'? You can do two things: 1. you are actually creating instances of your class and myFirstText and mySecondText are supposed to be different for every instance (let's say like 'age' of every instance of a person). In that case simply remove 'static' from the funcion declarations. 2. they are supposed to be static variables (shared amongs all the instances /if there are some/) - then declare the variables as  private static. edit: pls do not remove the comments